# Whenever I try to publish a post in wordpress, I always get redirected to the installation page...why?

Tags: redirect, installation

Whenever I try to publish I post, I get redirected to the /wp-admin/install.php page.  The file install.php is on the server but do I have to delete it?  I recently updated a handful of plugins and after the update finished, the redirect started happening.  Happens on Firefox and Chrome (the latest versions).  I'm just wondering why would Wordpress redirect to the installation page everytime I try to publish a post?  And then after the redirect occurs, if I try to relogin to wordpress or go to the wp-admin page, and each page redirects to the installation page.  The url would look like this: mysite.com/wp-login.php/wp-admin/install.php.  I don't understand.  Help would be appreciated.  And yes, I did clear the cache on both browsers.  I'm using the latest version of wordpress.

EDIT: Maybe after about 5-8 minutes, the site would work again and not redirect.  But the redirect would happen if I tried to publish a post again.

Comment: What Plugins do you have installed? (More importantly: which Plugins did you update before you started observing this behavior?)

Answer (score 1):

> I recently updated a handful of plugins and after the update finished,
>   the redirect started happening.

1) Try *deactivating* those plugins and reactivate them one by one until the problem reoccurs.

2) Try Debug and see what PHP errors you might be getting. See https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG

Add

`define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);`

in wp-config.php and the debug.log file will be in wp-content.

Change the "display" line to true

`define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);`

to dump them to the browser as well as log them.

Comment: problem is i forgot which plugins i updated. is there a way to figure out what plugins were recently updated? The redirect error is temporarily fixed when I do a repair on the wp_options database table in phpmyadmin.

Comment: Try deactivating them all, and reactivate them one by one until the problem reoccurs.

Comment: Is there any way that a person can see the most recent changes that happened in their wordpress site or the most recently update plugins?

Comment: Seems like my problem is solved.  My webhosting company increased my database size and then I did a repair and then relogged to wordpress.

Comment: They must have increased your hosting accounts php *memory allocation*, not your database size. Sounds like WP was running out of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

I know this questions might be quite old, but we had a similar problem:

When we published some changes in a page or cpt we got redirected to the post overview page.

We found out that the new changes we wanted to include would have hit the limit of the webspace.

After we aligned more webspace we were able to publish the changes accordingly.